# Why does uploading a file with no error need a check with equality?

Tags: php, file-upload, error-handling

This code seems to work fine for me when checking if there is an error when uploading a file.

```php
if ($_FILES['file']['error']) {
  // handle the error
} else {
  // process
}
```

However, [one comment](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php#99304) in the php docs says this should not work. The [top comment](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php#89374) does not mention it specifically, but it uses `if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)` in its example. Is there something I'm missing or are these comments just outdated?

Comment: I just do `if ( !empty($_FILES['FileField']['tmp_name']) ) { ...ok... } else { ...error... }` ... but, I'm oldschool.

Comment: It's no matter.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, although curiosity will probably get the best of me, but I have a really hard time believing that 0 would evaluate as true as that comment states. Also, the comment is quite old, and a lot has happened with PHP since then. I usually take those comment from the PHP docs with a grain of salt.